# How does targeting work for the Poison Spray cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, cantrips

*Poison spray* targets only one creature (at a range of 10 feet), but the description talks about "a puff of noxious gas [projected] from your palm." sounds like it should affect a creature that's in between the target and the caster (which it obviously doesn't, given RAW).

What's the position, given the [Living Rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20151111013154/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20140623) and so on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> You extend your hand toward a creature you can see
>   within range and project a puff of noxious gas from your
>   palm. The creature must succeed on a Constitution
>   saving throw or take 1d12 poison damage. (BD&D p98)

It's targeted at 1 creature. It affects 1 creature.

This is not an area attack, it's a directed attack. It's not a spell attack, so the additional creature doesn't grant cover, or even advantage.

Only the target is directed to make a saving throw or take damage so he is the only one affected.

It's worth noting that although this seems *less* directed than a ranged attack, the rule is similar. Basically everyone is moving all around in their space, you couldn't be shooting your poison *at* someone in an intervening space, but past them. The way I'd *picture* this is that those folks might get a *whiff* of the poison, but it's less of a *puff* and more of a directed *jet* at the target.

"Living Rules" is simply a way of talking about how they plan to make system updates and has no effect on a ruling in a case like this. A DM, I suppose, could use the freedom they are granted to make a ruling that additional creatures are affected, but it seems like the effects of the spell are intended for one creature only and other rulings may be quite unbalanced.